# Getting an image into a DIV object from a relational database

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am currently changing the code for a Web application (written with Angular.JS and the ionic framework with jQuery) that has a page generator. This generator page writes the image information into a relational database (phpMyAdmin, 10.1.22-MariaDB). What I have to do is to add a new form to this app where the user selects an existing page from a list & opens it in the page generator.

The *div* element that holds the image object is created in the page generator with a *$templateCache.put* command and has the following form:

```
"$templateCache.put("ivm-image-builder/templates/image-builder.html", "
"<div class=\"hero\"\n" +
    […]
"       <div class=\"hero-image\" ivm-bg-axis=\"y\" ivm-bg-drag ivm-bg-disabled=\"disabled\" ng-style=\"imageOptions.style\" ngf-background=\"ngModel\"></div>\n" +
    […]
```

The code runs properly when creating a new page. When using this generator page for an existing page that had been saved in the database, I can easily fill the text fields (like "page name" or "URL" (a text field)), but I wonder how the images can be displayed properly. I wonder if a *longtext* field or a *BLOB* is the appropriate field type in the DB.

**Edit:** To save the image in a database record, I need something that reads in pseudo-code

```js
var cache = new BrowserCache();

var imageURL= cache.querySelector('url["blob:null/520cf0e0-fa19-438c-9db7-68af87f30f56"]');

var image = cache.getElement(imageURL);

// Convert image to appropriate format, if necessary
// Add image information to record to be sent to the server
```

**My question is:** How can I display an image received from the database, which has no associated URI & is not saved at any accessible location? Is it the right way to associate the image information with the *ngModel* tag?

Comment: Commenting to come back later once anyone understands this question. For the poster: is there a way you can remove the irrelevant information and specify the actual problem you are facing?

Comment: I shortened the question.

Comment: have you looked into using base64 encoding ?
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding

Comment: Do you think the image in the browser cache is a string? I read in the link you sent about the `WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope.btoa()` method that it creates a base-64 encoded ASCII string from a `String` object, where each character is treated as a byte.